# Is there an equivalent to Mathematica's ToString in R for use with RLink?

Tags: rlink

```
x = "vvvv"
REvaluate["f(\"vvvv\")"]  (*works*)
```

Want to replace vvvv with x:

```
Revaluate["f(\"toString(x)\")"] (*doesn't work*)

Revaluate["f(toString(x))"]  (*doesn't work*)
```

Comment: ... but `x` is already a String; why do you need to carry out any conversion?

Comment: Does "REvaluate" vs. "Revaluate" have something to do with it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: thank you for your comment:  I don't know about the conversion question; perhaps R is not interpreting x as the string vvvv

Comment: thank you for pointing out the Re vs RE issue; I apologize for my typing error and failure to notice; unfortunately the error was here only and is not the problem

Comment: I don't have a copy of RLink loaded to test but wouldn't you want something like `REvaluate["f("<>x<>")"]` which would concatenate the strings?  Or maybe `REvaluate["f(\""<>x<>"\")"]` if the argument in `f` is to be a string?

Comment: Thank you again.  Have tried what I believe you are suggesting.  Revaluate["f("<>"\"x\""<>")"]  (doesn't work)  REvaluate["f("<>"\"vvvv\""<>")"]  (works)

Comment: Trying again. Have tried what I believe you are suggesting. REvaluate["f("<>"\"x\""<>")"] (doesn't work) REvaluate["f("<>"\"vvvv\""<>")"] (works)

Comment: AFAICT, this is a question about R.  If so, I think it is unreasonable to expect an answer for it from mathematica.stackexchange.com.  Maybe it should be posted in stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps . . . my reasoning was that the question required knowledge of both Mathematica and R.  An R expert may have no knowledge of Mathematica; however, a Mathematica user of RLink must have some knowledge of R, no?

Comment: Please remember you can accept the answer that solves your problem by clicking the checkmark sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this a bit verbose but does this help:

```
(* Define a function that returns the argument *)
REvaluate["f <- function(v) {v};"]

(* Define the value for a variable *)
x = "vvvv";

(* Construct the REvaluate argument *)
arg = "f(\"" <> x <> "\")"
(* f("vvvv") *)

(* Evaluate function *)
REvaluate[arg]
(* {"vvvv"} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  To be sure I understand it, you suggest

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  To be sure I understand it, you suggest REvaluate["g <- function(v) {v};"]; x = "vvvv"; arg = 
 "g(\"" <> x <> "\")"; REvaluate["f(arg)"]  Is this correct?

Comment: No.  You just want `arg` rather than `"f(arg)"`.  You could certainly skip the `arg = ` step and put that constructed string right in the `REvaluate` statement.  I think where you went wrong is not surrounding `x` with the string concatenation operators `<>`.  That's why I separated out the `arg` to make that string creation explicit and isolated from the other commands.  If you have a particular function (where you've written `f` and `g`), then an example could be more tailored to your needs.

Comment: Yes; I believe you have correctly located my error which was quite a challenge given my lack of experience with R and RLink.  Your help is greatly appreciated.  I am a first time poster here and will try to determine how to mark your answer as the remedy.  Thank you again.